# Communicating to an Arduino chip in C on a windows machine

Tags: c, windows, arduino

I am trying to talk to my Arduino using a C program though a virtual com port (USB). The computer is running Windows and I am compiling the program using BloodShed. All I need is a basic communications library, but all I found so far is old libraries that could not compile on my machine.

Any suggestions on what I can use?

Comment: By Bloodshed I take it you mean [Dev-C++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info)?

Comment: Dev-C++ is *ancient*. Go get any of the (free) better alternatives like Visual C++ express or Code::Blocks. Anything but Dev-C++.

Comment: @Insilico What about the Visual C++ Express? What recommendations would you have for that compiler?

Comment: @jakebird451, VC++ is Microsoft's own compiler. Start there, for that reason. (It's also a pretty good development environment).

Comment: @Ben Do you know of a specific communications example before I try to integrate things over to VC++?

Comment: @jakebird451: Visual C++ Express isn't a compiler, it's an integrated development environment like Dev-C++. The Visual C++ compiler is separate from the IDE, but the Visual C++ compiler comes with the IDE. As long as you use standard C++, it should compile fine, but you may want to play around with it first before you try to migrate everything over first.

Comment: @Insilico I'm sorry, I should have said it's compiler.

Comment: @jakebird451: What about it? It's a fine C++ compiler, but I recommend that you compile with `/W4` and `/WX` set. This increases the warning levels and turns warnings into errors, so you can catch as many potential bugs as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really are just trying to communicate with it over a USB to serial adapter then this may be of interest:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120905123232/http://robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf

Looks like on windows you can just read and write to the COM port as if it were a file

As far as C++ IDEs go, QtCreator is fairly decent even if you're not using the Qt libraries.

Comment: Very interesting document. I will review it and get back to you.

Comment: @jakebird451 I need the file but the link is not working. Can you post it?

Comment: @user2192774 The Internet Archive still has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20120905123232/http://robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Rigging up a simple WinForms app using C#.NET should be easy enough.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/communicating-with-serial-port-in-C-Sharp/

You can use Visual C# Express 2010. ( Download link here : [Visual C# 2010 Express full download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119698/visual-c-sharp-2010-express-full-download) )